# How to remove multiple network payloads of the save asset that have ?__WB_REVISION in url

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I have website that I want to optimize [urosjarc.com](https://urosjarc.com), but I can't manage to remove
double network payloads making end payload size twice as big as it supposed to be.

I'm using vue 2 with PWA support (service worker) with Appache server. How can I remove this double network calls, making end payload size smaller.

[image]

Comment: Disable prefetch/preload. https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5562

Answer (score 0):

The `__WB_REVISION__` parameter requests are generated by [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) during the precaching step of service worker installation.

If you're dealing with URLs that already include hashes in them (which appears to be the case), then you can avoid those extra requests by [configuring](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/module-workbox-webpack-plugin.GenerateSW#:%7E:text=its%20directory%20index.-,dontCacheBustURLsMatching,-Optional) the Workbox build tool being used "under the hood" to recognize those hashes. Setting `dontCacheBustURLsMatching: /\.[0-9a-f]{8}\./` would seem to be the right configuration for your usage, where there's an 8 character hash surrounded by `.`.

Additionally, if you're using `workbox-webpack-plugin` v6.x and `webpack` v4.40+ or v5.x, you wouldn't need to configure anything extra, as Workbox will [make use of new `immutable` metadata](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/pull/2673) that `webpack` adds to assets that include hashes.